# Explicit type casting, array of derived class

Tags: java, inheritance, casting

```
class Animal{ }
class Cat extends Animal{ }

public class Main
{     
    public static void main(String ab[])
    {   
        Animal[] objAnimal = {new Cat()};
        Cat objCat0 = (Cat)objAnimal[0]; // a valid operation.
        Cat[] objCatArray = (Cat[]) objAnimal; //not a valid operation.
    }
}
```

I am trying to understand what is happening behind the scenes.

Why `Cat objCat0 = (Cat)objAnimal[0];` is a valid operation and `Cat[] objCatArray = (Cat[]) objAnimal;` is not?

Comment: You can cast `Cat[]` to `Animal[]`, but not the other way around. An array of `Animal` may contain a `Dog`, which will break if you assume that it only contains `Cat`s

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Could you please help me with documentations about the concept?

Comment: I'm probably the wrong person to ask that. I will base my answer on the [Java Language Specification §4.10.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.3), which is the source of truth, but not easy to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Animal[] objAnimal = {new Cat()};
```

is a shortcut for

```
Animal[] objAnimal = new Animal[] {new Cat()};
```

which is a shortcut for

```
Animal[] objAnimal = new Animal[1];
objAnimal[0] = new Cat();
```

The compiled code is identical. So looking at the last variant, it should become obvious that you can do

```
Cat objCat0 = (Cat)objAnimal[0];
```

because you previously stored a reference to a `Cat` instance, created via `new Cat()`, to `objAnimal[0]` whereas

```
Cat[] objCatArray = (Cat[]) objAnimal;
```

is invalid because `objAnimal` contains a reference to an `Animal[]` array instance, created via `new Animal[1]`. The fact that there’s a `Cat` reference stored in one element doesn’t change the type of the array. There could be a subsequent `objAnimal[0] = new Animal();` at any time.

The array initializer syntax used in your question exists for convenience, but doesn’t change the logic. So

```
Animal[] objAnimal = {new Cat()};
objAnimal[0] = new Animal();
```

is valid and

```
Cat[] objCatArray = (Cat[]) objAnimal;
```

must fail as otherwise you could subsequently use

```
Cat cat = objCatArray[0];
```

without a cast, despite the possibility of the `objAnimal[0] = new Animal()` assignment.